# Ledger Nano S Public Key Hash Changed

Tags: ledger, error, transfer

I created a  and a  on my ledger nano s and delegated the tezzies.

Upon attempting to send one tez back to my fundraiser wallet, I executed the following command:

```
transfer 1 from <KT originated address> to <fundraiser address>
```

The output was:

Insufficient information: you need to provide a curve & BIP32 path

So I ran:

```
 tezos-client import secret key ledger_name_ed "ledger://<ledger tz address>/0'/0'" --force
```

The resulting public key hash did not match the

Now when I run:

```
transfer 1 from <KT originated address> to <fundraiser address>
```

the output is:

```
Error:
  no keys for the source contract manager
```

I have a feeling the ledger is not generating the same public key hash because the input for the bip path changed.

Has anyone had this issue? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my own question the fix was to correct the import command as follows

```
tezos-client import secret key <alias> "ledger://<animals>/ed25519" --force
```